# How do you record video with animated overlay in Android?

Tags: android, video, camera, overlay, record

I'm new to programming and Android.  I'm designing a game that uses the phone camera. One of the key features of my app will be recording a live video feed from the camera with an animated overlay.

Some examples of apps that already do this:

- Snapchat
- various dash cam apps
- like this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.busywww.dashboardcam
- etc

I'm researching which platforms would be best for this task. Some candidates I've found are:

- OpenGL ES
- LibGDX
- Unity3D
- Android Camera2 API
- Android Camera API
- CWAC-2 Android Camera API Wrapper

I've read that Android Camera2 API is limited to Lollipop or higher and that Android Camera API is being deprecated. I also asked the author of CWAC-2 and he said that it's not possible with his library.

So, that leaves the top 3 as candidates. Which of those would be easiest to implement, offer the widest compatibility and have the highest quality results?

What would be the best framework for doing this task?

Thank you!

Comment: So, did you find any solution yet?

Comment: No, no, not yet.

Comment: If you have in mind a game, i could point you to Unity, with is the facto tool to do this. You always could go to native (im native, not unity developer) but im sure you will fight on native code and do the rest of the project on other tool/language, so 2 times work. LibGDX i know its usefull too but im not sure if out of the box have everything about the camera

Comment: hey @Tom did you find any solution to do this?

Comment: @ND1010_:  Sorry, no solution yet.